# How to save user name and password in Login screen Open erp

Tags: authentication, passwords, save, browser-cache, odoo

I used google chrome, and when I login to open erp there is no option to save the password,
the username is restore but I want to keep the password automatically fill in the field, does anybody know how to do it?
I used mozila and there is option to save but it doesnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you click on "More" option in user Screen, you'll have an option "Reset User Password", click on it and you have a screen to change password.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: passwords can be saved - just not automatically reused when the corresponding username is entered. I don't have a work-around for that problem, but I can rule out the two methods usually employed to do this:-

- _autocomplete disabled
- two password fields

The same technique is used on the openerp.com website (it's the same software). Accounts are free and a solution would be most appreciated (it makes testing a pain).

If you are actually not able to save a password (do check in your password manager), check:-

**Firefox -> Preferences -> Security -> Passwords**
Tick **Remember Passwords** and check for an entry in **Exceptions**